# Exception is thrown at Main Function instead of actual line of code

Tags: c#, exception

**Update 2:**
Now question is not about chartArea error. Its only about breaking at the point(code line) of exception. See what i get other error. Again at main
[image]

**Update :**
During development i want every exception to be thrown as early as it occurs. So see this image, I have tried to throw all exceptions and this works great for me. Visual studio usually tell me the exact line what causes error [image] 
But in following case I had already spent more than two hours looking at all options of exception details (with hit and trial because I don't know exactly what will tell me the error lines) but could not find anyway where exactly is the problem with my code or data.

[image]

**Actual Question**

I am working on c# desktop app which contains MS Charts. On executing a particular report, I get an error shown in image. Problem is how i am unable to get this error exactly at the point (line of code) of its actual occurrence. So i would fix that line.

When I debug the code before getting this error, every line goes fine and again exception occurs in Main function. But Main function is fine for all other cases

[image: Image of error]

Comment: Try to [Break on User-Unhandled Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/038tzxdw.aspx).

Comment: If you click on the "View Detail..." link, you will see the full exception, including stack trace. Since you don't have an exception handler in your `FrmMainScreen` class itself (or whatever form is where the exception occurs), it propagates up to the event loop, where the only user code is your call to `Application.Run()`. But the exception detail has all the information you need.

Comment: I could not exactly understand but I tried `Break on User_unhanded exception` and my update is the result. I though that exception of DataVisualazation.Charting might be missing form CLR so i tried to add it (see first image) in list but I think it did take no effect. There might be some more to do to add it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `ChartAreaCollection` using the string indexer and have passed empty string as value like below somewhere in your code (probably in the constructor).

```
chart1.ChartAreas[""]
```

I tried in a sample code and get the same error what you have got. Only difference is that it exactly breaks in the line where I access the collection using `""`. Search your code for `[""]` and you are most likely to find it.

Comment: Thanks for the special attention dear. But the challenge is breaking it, chart is left behind. I have updated my question .

Answer (score 0):

You added a component on your form which didn't have a name assigned to it.

Compare all your ChartAreaCollection components and see if it has a name or not

Comment: although it says that the name ´´ *cannot be found*. Not that it cannot be added. Wouldn't that mean that it is related to searching and not adding? How should the OP find the code that throws the error (which seems to be the question)?.

Comment: Exactly @Default that is the question. However in debugging I have no empty named chartArea in chartareacollection. Its count is 1 and one element's name is chartArea1. That is what i have seen using immediate window